# Converting Adobe Flash Player video file of .exe format to windows video format

Tags: adobe, flash

want to convert a adobe flash player video of .EXE FORMAT to format that can be played in any windows player such as windows media player, vlc, 123 etc.....

Answer (score 1):

EXE is not a video format, it's an executable.

If you have an executable that was made in Flash and contains a video there are two possibilities: Either it has the video embedded on the timeline, or it loads the video from an remote location. One clue to this would be the file size (if the exe just plays a video and it's more than a 5 or 6MB it's probably embedded). Alternatively try loading it with no network connectivity - if it works then it's inline, if not it's remote (probably).

If it's loaded from a remote location - good news! Use Charles Proxy, or decompile the exe (see below) to figure our where it's downloading from.

If not, then you could try decompiling the exe unto a FLA using something like this http://www.swf-decompiler.com/flash-exe-decoder and then export/encode from Flash

Comment: Great this sound like it would work. I am going to try these solutions and give you a feedback